# Regex to covert URL into parts

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a few URLs like

```
https//abc.domain-name.co

https//*.domain-name.co 

*//*.domain-name.co
```

here * means there can be catch-all condition. e.g

> *//.domains > all protocols allowed

I need a regex to extract

1. protocols
2. domain
3. subdomain
4. hostname

Required Result :

```
for : *//posts.com

 "protocol": "*",
 "hostname": "posts.com",

for *//*.posts.com
  protocol: '*',
  hostname: '*.posts.com',
```

I can not use URL(js) as that need a valid Url and adding * makes a url invalid, that's why a regex is needed to parse the url into an array of strings.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? There is an [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) object that can parse these for you.

Comment: Can you please tell expected output

Comment: Can you tell us more about what the purpose of this is?

Comment: URL dosent work because adding * will make a url invalid

Comment: @MuhammadShaharyar Your question is too broad but after your last comment, it became unclear as well. Please edit your question to clarify (show expected output, etc.) _and_ include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand what you're asking, these should be the regex to catch subdomain, domain and protocol:

- Subdomain: `\/\/([a-z]+)\.`
- Domain: `\:\/\/[a-z]+\.(.*)\.`
- Protocol: `([a-z]+)\:\/\/`

So if we test out the following code:

```
var str = "https://abc.domain-name.co";

var patt_subdomain = /\/\/([a-z]+)\./i;
var patt_protocol = /([a-z]+)\:\/\//i;
var patt_domain = /\:\/\/[a-z]+\.(.*)/i;

var subdomain = str.match(patt_subdomain);
var protocol = str.match(patt_protocol);
var domain = str.match(patt_domain);


console.log("Subdomain: " + subdomain[1]);
console.log("Protocol: " + protocol[1]);
console.log("Domain: " + domain[1]);
```

This is the output:

```
Subdomain: abc
Protocol: https
Domain: domain-name.co
```

It's basically based on the fact that `://` is a constant in any URL, and `. (dot)` divide URL into parts. So for example subdomain catches the `[a-z]+` group between `//` and `. (dot)`. Please note that the first regex catches the whole domain if the URL does not have any subdomain.

**EDIT (BETTER SOLUTION)**

As @Rup mentioned in the comments here's a single regex solution:

```
var str = "https://abc.domain-name.co";

var patt = /(.*)\:\/\/([a-z]+)\.(.*)/i;

var result = str.match(patt);


console.log("Subdomain: " + result[2]);
console.log("Protocol: " + result[1]);
console.log("Domain: " + result[3]);
```

Comment: If it were me I think I'd rather see a single regex with multiple groups rather than three separate ones.

Comment: You're right I edited the domain part, and I'll going for the single regex solution, good advice!